# Random letters appearing in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm editing a document Word 2013 on Windows 8.1 and the document is located in my OneDrive folder.  I am getting random letters appearing in the document as I type.  I made a short video of the problem here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zW8H8cqjX2U

Although this is happening very regularly, I cannot reliably reproduce the behaviour.  It does seem to happen close to when I go back and edit a section of a sentence that has already been written.

I have [turned off animations](http://www.howtogeek.com/161826/how-to-disable-the-typing-animation-feature-in-office-2013/) and that has not solved the problem (note that animations are on in the video above).

Comment: Does it happen with different keyboards?

Comment: Have tried it with another keyboard, but I've not managed to get it to reproduce today with either!

Comment: Did you inherit a haunted computer?

Comment: Quite possibly! :)